# Mass is a stuff or not?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, popular-science, mass-energy

Einstein said, there can be no clear definition can be give for moving body mass – instead of giving its name as “rest mass”, it is better to mention, “momentum and energy”. Matter is a stuff, particles and fields are stuffs – but “mass” is not a stuff?

Comment: Mass is a property of stuff.

Comment: laymen language often uses mass for "stuff",  but in physics it is a property describing inertia (resistance to change in velocity)

Comment: Xurtio, it is "resistance to change in velocity" or "resistance to change in momentum?"

Comment: Historical point: I highly doubt Einstein ever said any such thing. He *showed* that the mass of a body is a relativistic *invariant* equal to $\sqrt{E^2/c^4 - p^2 /c^2}$. Don't believe what you hear on the television. Their job is to confuse you with non-standard and conflicting terminology and distracting special effects. Physicists don't use any other mass than "the rest mass" and that is perfectly well defined.

Answer (score 2):

Mass can be equated to 'amount of stuff' only in the non-relativistic (slow speed) limit.

In a relativistic treatment the term 'mass' loses its meaning as 'amount of stuff'. Rather, it can be defined as the invariant length of the energy-momentum four-vector of the system. Effectively, it is the magnitude of the energy-momentum vector, a quantity that can be measured as the total energy in the comoving (zero total momentum) frame of the system under consideration.

It really helps in understanding relativity if you avoid the use of the term 'mass'. All you need is energy-momentum. Inertia as well as gravity follow from energy-momentum.